Getting Extra Text in Output from Deployed LLM in Vertex AI despite Specified Format
I'm encountering an issue with a deployed LLM (llama 3 8b instruct model) in Vertex AI. Despite specifying the output format, I'm consistently getting extra text along with the desired output.
The expecting output is in dict for example
{
"key": "value",
"key": ["values"]
}

However, what I'm actually receiving is:
\. Ignition disengagment strateggy\n\n" and "OTHerr fuel
\xc2\xb5njetion Stratgy\n"

{
"key": "value",
"key": ["values"]
}

import re
import enchant
import difflib
import langid

def to_title_case(text):
    return re.sub(r'([A-Z])', r' \1', text).strip()

def get_language(text):
    language = langid.classify(text)[0]
    return language

def spell_check(text):
    d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
    words = text.split()
    mispelled = [word for word in words if not d.check(word)]
    if mispelled:
        suggestions = [enchant.suggest(word, d) for word in mispelled]
        suggestions = [suggestion for suggestion in suggestions if suggestion]
        suggestions = ", ".join(suggestions)
    else:
        suggestions = "No suggestions"
    return suggestions


Hi @Jacob Gokul, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
